# Prevent noise data in outputstream when calling exe using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, npm, cmd, process

I want to get the version number of a package using the following npm command:

```
npm show webpack version
```

In my `proc_OutputDataReceived` event-handler I get noise data upfront,
you can see the ouput in the comments of the event-handler.

**Is it possible to prevent the noise data and only get the version number or do I have to parse the output?**

```
 public static string getVersionInfo()
{

    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {       
        FileName = "cmd",
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UseShellExecute= false,
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\...",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true
    };

    var proc = Process.Start(psi);

    proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += Proc_ErrorDataReceived;
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("npm show webpack version & exit"); 
    proc.WaitForExit();

}

static void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Data);
    // prints:
    // "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112]"
    // "(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved."
    // ""
    // "C:\\Users...\\workingFolder>npm show webpack version & exit"
    // "4.12.0"   <-- THIS IS THE DESIRED RESULT !!!
    // null
}
```

Comment: You're spawning a shell and sending text to it, have you considered just executing `cmd.exe /C npm show webpack version` directly?

Comment: What do you mean with directly, in the console (cmd.exe) itself, of course this works, but I want to execute it from my .NET app and prevent all the initial output data. Perhaps I didn't get you...

Comment: I don't want the following upfront:
// "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112]"
    // "(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved."
    // ""
    // "C:\\Users...\\workingFolder>npm show webpack version & exit"

Comment: Set Arguments to "/C npm show webpack version", and skip redirecting input, see if that helps.

Comment: yes, this works, thanks a lot! I will accept your answer with a little explanation, just post it below.

Comment: What about `npm show webpack version >&2` and then capture the _STD_ERR_ stream (handle `2`) only?

Comment: @aschipfl supplied via `Arguments` or `StandardInput`?

Comment: I don't know; maybe try both variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're spawning a shell, and then sending commands to it, this will print out information from the shell program as well as the command you want to execute.

The solution is to ask the shell program, `cmd`, to simply execute your program directly.

This can be done by just passing the program to the `cmd.exe` executable as arguments, prefixed by `/C` to "execute and exit".

So here's the changes you need to do:

1. Add `Arguments`
2. Remove `RedirectStandardInput`
3. Don't send commands to the shell

Now you should have:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{       
    FileName = "cmd",
    Arguments = "/C npm show webpack version",
    UseShellExecute= false,
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\...",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};
```

Then remove the line that sends commands to the shell:

```
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("npm show webpack version & exit");  // delete
```

And that should be it.